# align 3 divs in the center under 4 divs

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I have 4 div tags each one is a day ex. **monday , tuesday , wednesday, thursday, etc.**. I have the 4 aligned by float left each `200px` wide. Now I have 3 div tags each one is a day also **friday saturday sunday**, and I want to center this underneath the 4 that are above.

```
<div id= "top-four-days">   
    <br />
    <div class= "monday">
       <h2>Monday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
     </div>
     <div class= "tuesday">
       <h2>Tuesday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
     </div>
     <div class= "wednesday">
       <h2>Wednesday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
     </div>
     <div class= "thursday">
       <h2>Thursday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id= "bottome-three-days">   
    <br />
    <div class= "friday">
       <h2>Friday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class= "saturday">
       <h2>Saturday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class= "sunday">
       <h2>Sunday</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
       <h2>Evening</h2>
       <br />
       <h3>Date:</h3>
       <h3>Time:</h3>
       <h3>Location:</h3>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**style**

```
#top-four-days {
    width: 800px;       
    }
#bottom-three-days {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #999;
    }

.monday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: purple; 
    float: left;        
}

.tuesday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F00;
    float: left;    
}

.wednesday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue; 
    float: left;        
}

.thursday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;        
}

.friday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;        
}
.saturday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;        
}
.sunday {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qiqiabaziz/FmPhg)? You can use `inline-block` together with `text-align:center;` in order to centering them.